# Spinner вместо заголовка (toolbar)

Tags: android, toolbar

В каком то приложении мне попадался спиннер вместо заголовка в toolbar. Как такое реализовать? Дайте, пожалуйста, наводку.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377760/adding-spinner-to-actionbar-not-navigation оно?

Comment: По ссылке приведенной Вами описывается, как добавить спиннер вместо меню, но как разместить его в том месте, где должен отображаться заголовок?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Делается элементарно:

1. В `Toolbar` помещается `Spinner`

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   ...
   >
       <Spinner
           android:id="@+id/spinner"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   ```
2. В `Activity` прописываем что наш `Toolbar` будет выполнять функции `ActioBar`'a и то, что не хотим отображать заголовок

   ```
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
   ```

Вот собственно говоря и все, с заполнением `Spinner`'a я думаю сложностей возникнуть не должно =)

Результат (аля вк):

[image: результ]